# How do I use parameterized types in ruby-pg (the new postgres library for ruby)?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

The documentation ( http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-exec ) suggests that to insert types like booleans or dates, I should use code like this:

```
db_object.exec("INSERT INTO dan_test_1 (one) VALUES ($1)",
    { :value => "true",
      :type  => 16,
      :format => 1
     } );
```

(I looked up "16" in the pg_type table.)

But I keep on getting errors like "can't format (PGError)".

I can insert strings and numbers, just fine, but how do I handle these other common types?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem? It's a much easier path when talking to a database.

Comment: Is that the new supported library?  ruby's "postgres" was abandoned and replaced by "pg".  Has "pg" been abandoned, too?

Comment: Those are drivers, used to connect. Sequel is an ORM providing several abstraction layers that uses the "pg" gem to connect to PostgreSQL's client lib. "pg" is the supported gem. "postgres" is the name Sequel uses internally to connect in its DSN. Read http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The docs you link to actually recommend using common text formats (`'t'` for true, `'2012-11-26'` for dates, ...) and explicit casts in the SQL if needed:

> Instead of specifying type oids, it’s recommended to simply add explicit casts in the query to ensure that the right type is used.

So if `one` is a boolean column, you would want this:

```
db_object.exec("INSERT INTO dan_test_1 (one) VALUES ($1)", [ 't' ])
```

Sequel may help you but you really should know what's going on behind your back anyway.

Comment: That example can work, but it only inserts 'true'.  I still get errors trying to put in dates.  (This is Ruby 1.8, if it matters.)

Comment: @DanJameson: And for dates you'd `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` them into ISO 8601 format, timestamps would use `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, etc.

Comment: db_object.exec("INSERT INTO dan_test_2 (two) VALUES ($1)",  [ '2001-01-28' ]  )

in `exec': can't format (PGError)

Comment: That works fine for me. Have you tried an explicit cast (`values ($1::date)`)?